# operar de forma automatica valores de otras tablas al insertar un campo

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sum

queria consultar si hay una manera de que en un determinado campo de una tabla al dejar en null opere de forma automatica valores de otras tablas, por ejemplo lo que me gustaria hacer es que en una tabla de 'productos' con un atributo precio, en otra tabla como por ejemplo 'ventas' con un atributo monto, y luego otra tabla 'detalle_venta' que relaciona de uno a muchos la tabla ventas con los productos, en el atributo monto al dejar en null primero tome de detalle_venta cuales productos estan relacionados con la venta y luego sume los precios de estos almacenados en productos. se que existe el condicional ifnull y el operador sum pero solo encontre el caso de sumar campos dentro de la misma tabla y no que haga consultas y opere de otras tablas.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: no entendi nada... vos podes sumar si joineas cualquier cosa.. pero no entendi tu problema en si..

Comment: Hay tres tablas, en una llamada 'ventas' hay un atributo 'monto', luego en otra tabla 'productos' hay un atributo 'precio', y luego en otra tabla 'detalle_venta' relaciona todos los productos que pertenecen a cada venta,  lo que quiero hacer es que no sea necesario aclarar el monto de cada venta sino que consulte de la tabla 'detalle_venta' los productos que pertenecen a la venta, y luego de esa lista saque los precios de la tabla 'productos'' y los sume.

Answer (score 0):

La consulta que estás buscando es esta:

```
UPDATE ventas JOIN (
    SELECT id_venta,SUM(cantidad*precio) importe
      FROM detalle_venta
      JOIN ventas USING(id_venta)
      JOIN productos USING(id_producto)
      WHERE monto IS NULL
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 USING(id_venta)
  set monto=importe;
```

Y puedes probarla a partir del dataset que describes en tu pregunta:

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
  id_producto int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  producto varchar(31),
  precio float
  );
CREATE TABLE ventas(
  id_venta int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  f_venta date,
  monto float
  );
CREATE TABLE detalle_venta(
  id_detalle_venta int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_venta int,
  id_producto int,
  cantidad float,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_venta) REFERENCES ventas(id_venta),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_producto) REFERENCES productos(id_producto)
  );
INSERT INTO ventas (f_venta)
  VALUES (NOW());
INSERT INTO productos (producto, precio)
  VALUES ('Suscripción',2);
INSERT INTO detalle_venta (id_venta, id_producto, cantidad)
  VALUES (1,1,1),(1,1,2);
```

Consiste básicamente en combinar la información de varias tablas, `JOIN` , y agrupar la información, `GROUP BY`, para después actualizar con `UPDATE` el campo calculado `monto`.

Esta consulta debes ejecutarla únicamente cuando des por completada una venta, no cada vez que insertes un detalle, pues únicamente te calcularía el total del primer detalle. La puedes meter en un disparador o ejecutarla tras la inserción de cada detalle con esta modificación:

```
UPDATE ventas JOIN (
    SELECT id_venta,SUM(cantidad*precio) importe
      FROM detalle_venta
      JOIN ventas USING(id_venta)
      JOIN productos USING(id_producto)
      WHERE id_venta=(
        SELECT id_venta FROM detalle_venta
          WHERE id_detalle_venta=1
      )
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 USING(id_venta)
  set monto=importe;
```

De esta forma, te actualizará el monto de toda la venta cada vez que modifiques o añadas algún detalle a esa misma venta que puedes identificar a través de su detalle.

Recuerda aportar el intento que hayas realizado a tu pregunta. Aunque no funcione, nos ayuda a saber cómo orientarte. Normalmente es condición necesaria para que respondamos aunque, en este caso concreto, me pareció un caso de facturación bastante típico que puede resultar bastante útil dejar documentado en SO. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.